# How is it possible that set size(both width and height) to the component in Codename one designer?

Tags: java, codenameone

I got a problem in codenameone designer, I cant find anything related to the sizing component.
I want to set size components in codenameone designer not implementing in the codes.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to look at this, you should not set size but instead trigger size which depends on your component type and your intentions. E.g. for text components set the columns/rows, for lists/combo boxes set the rendering prototype. You can also manipulate padding/margin/border/layout etc. to manipulate whitespace.

If you insist you can always bind a before*Show event and invoke `setPreferredSize` on the component.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is you can define margins, paddings and etc for component in codenameone designer but you can't define width and height there.

Comment: I want to find ways to define width and height of components in designer panel not in the code.

Comment: Select the theme and define it for the UIID matching the component UIID. You can modify the component UIID of any Component in the designer. See http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html

Comment: @Shai How 'bout an equivalent to Android's `wrap_content`?

Comment: Do you mean something like `FlowLayout`?